# Выборка из БД с последней записи?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Я только учу php, и для практики начал писать что-то типа чата. Код сначала вставляет сообщение в БД, потом вытаскивает его оттуда... но проблема в том, что извлекает из БД не с последнего, а с первого сообщения и тем самым новое сообщение выводится снизу страницы, а хотелось бы, чтобы оно выводилось сверху. Можно что-нибудь сделать? И еще, может кто-то подскажет правильно, какая последовательность должна быть у вывода сообщений?

Буду благодарен.

Comment: Код в студию, поля таблиц из БД тоже. какой запрос делаешь ну и  т.д.

Представь что ты на допросе в полиции России, тебе задают кучу вопросов.

Так вот чтобы не задавали кучу вопросов и отпустили невиновным, нужно сделать так (написать ксе запросы и нужные входные данные) чтобы вопросов было как можно меньше, и один единственный ответ оказался правильным и быстрым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При выборке сообщений из базы используйте конструкцию ORDER BY. [Здесь справочка по mysql](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Sorting_rows.html)
Как правило в чате новые сообщения появляются снизу и уходят на верх.

Comment: спасибо большее, особенно за справочник) почитал и все понял )

Answer (score 2):

Просто запрос нужно формировать как `{ЗДЕСЬ ТОТ ЖЕ ЗАПРОС, ЧТО И БЫЛ} ORDER BY id desc`, где id - уникальный идентификатор записи в базе.

Comment: и Вас спасибо большее

Comment: No Problem

Comment: и правда выводит все начиная с последней записи, но почему-то с выводом опаздывает) то есть пишешь текст, отправляешь в базу и он оттуда сразу должен вывести) такого не происходит) происходит, то что сначало заносит в базу ничего не выводя на экран, а потом при повторном только нажатии выводит) почему так? а вот если делать без
ORDER BY id desc, то выводит прекрасно )

Answer (score 2):

В реляционной БД отсутствует понятие первая/последняя запись. Порядок выдачи записи определяется сортировкой результата, а это в свою очередь определяется инструкцией `ORDER BY`. В данном контексте, выдачу надо оформить примерно так:

```
SELECT MESSAGE_TIME, MESSAGE_TEXT from CHAT_MESSAGES ORDER BY MESSAGE_TIME DESC
```

В этом случае выдача будет отсортирована по убыванию времени сообщения (поле MESSAGE_TIME), так что самое свежее сообщение будет выдано первым.

Comment: спасибо не только за код, но и за полное разъяснение

Answer (score 1):

Или, как пример, можно заюзать PHP-функцию "mysql_fetch_array(ЗАПРОС)", которая
возвращает поочередно записи, подходящие под запрос. В вашем случае это так:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM <имя таблицы в БД>");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    // скопировать массив $data в глобальный
} // в итоге в глобальном массиве будет находиться последняя запись
```